# Being sick working in childcare

Tags: work-environment, sickness, australia, children

I’m a trainee at a day care centre, and I’ve had a lot of time off sick due to the flu I caught from the kids.

Work has put a lot of pressure on me to come back to work when I haven’t fully recovered, making it hard to shake the flu. I went into work, after a few hours I felt sick and was throwing up. I got told if I was going to be sick I should have called in that morning and that they weren’t going to look for a cover and that I had to stay and finish the day.

I did, but I feel confused because I get in trouble for being away sick, but if I do what they want and come in sick I also get in trouble. They make snarky comments about how knowing my record I can’t just take one day off to get better and make me feel really bad about being sick even though I can’t control if I have influenza.

Are they allowed to treat me like this? My goal here is that I want to be treated with some type of respect towards my health because in general I don’t feel like I am treated as well because I’m not as old or have as much experience as everyone else.

Comment: How would you prefer to be treated? I.e., what goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be treated with some type of respect towards my health and I’m general I don’t feel like I am treated as well because I’m not as old or have as much experience as everyone else

Comment: So they knowingly forced the children at the day center to be around someone who has the flu because they are too lazy to try to find someone to cover for you?

Comment: Basically yes I had to work with vomit on me that I couldn’t wipe off my pants and be around the children with the flu because they didn’t want to find a cover and I felt like it was disrespectful to me and negligent towards the children’s health

Comment: Wow there is a heap of word that wish for being turned into sentences :-) Such text is hard to understand because the only period is at the end.

Comment: Please edit your post. This is a text-communication, it's incredibly hard to read and understand your train-of-thought typing. Write this post as if it was a written communication to a non-native speaker, where you want to do your best to make the reader understand you.

Comment: @puck: Yes, exactly. I edited the question to make it readable - but IMHO it still needs work on the content level to be a useful question.

Comment: Joe I’ve missed 8 days not all bunched together because they pushed me to come back when I was still sick but for every day I have had off sick I have had a medical certificate and the doctor tell me I shouldn’t go back but whenever I take time off they tell me to reconsider my position

Comment: So the daycare that you work at not only requires sick employees to come to work (to infect the kids), but also allows sick children to attend?

Comment: Have you asked them if they would rather you come in while still sick and potentially spread your illness, or come back when you are well and fit to do the job. Some companies have back to work interviews to make sure you are definitely fit to come back to work (although they can just be a paper exercise sometimes)

Comment: Sick children are allowed at the daycare aslong as there not running a fever they don’t check vaccinations of the children or the employees, I have asked them would they rather me sick or well and I got hit with a speech of do I even want to work with them why am I here really if I have something I have to tell them am I pregnant and that they have rules and procedures if I was going to throw up I should of called in sick at 7am and when I tried to explain I didn’t plan on being sick or I would of called they told me I have a responsibility to the poor children who’s parents are paying me

Answer (score 4):

Childcare in Australia as you know is and has been in very high demand especially in the large cities.  A lot of the centers are small with no real HR departments and pretty much at the mercy of the owner who is also often the person running the day to day business.  This limits your options in terms of what action can be taken.

In an ideal world you shouldn't be treated this way.  In the real world this sort of thing can happen anywhere and in any job where there are laws governing how many staff members must be on site for the business to remain open.  Childcare workers are plentiful with the TAFE's pumping them out at an industrial scale and as you know they are low paid workers.  (I absolutely disagree with how this is but thats besides the point I'm trying to make). The bottom line is this means the small center owners often see their staff as disposable.  Having the kids (and their parents) get attached to staff means nothing to them.  Some business owners are worse than others and in your case they were obviously unreasonable.

I know all this because my wife worked in (and ran) a childcare center in Australia for a long time before changing careers.

Unless you are working in a large center with a corporate body governing them unfortunately you might have to either play by their rules or find somewhere else to work.  Complaining to any government agency probably wouldn't be much help since nothing can be proven.

Good luck, I think you guys are very under appreciated.

Comment: +1 for your last note on under-appreciation of persons working in that field - Among other fields I fully agree on that one and hope the public eye/perception will show more gratitude in terms of respect & compensation!

Answer (score 0):

> Are they allowed to treat me like this?

There may not be a law against how they treat you (Especially If the 'bad treatment' is primarily on the lines of passing rude comments). However, there should be a company policy against it and you should check with your manager or HR if there is one and how to enforce it in your case.

If you are getting this treatment from your manager/HR, then I suppose there is nothing much you can do about it other than leaving.